# Terminate spring boot applications gracefully

Tags: linux, spring

I am developing a Spring Boot application for which I need to persist some cache data before termination. I have found that, in order to do it, I can implement the DisposableBean interface. However, is the code going to be executed if I kill the process using the "kill -9 " command?

Answer (score 0):

kill -9 causes process to immediately stop as definitions says:

```
The KILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate immediately.
In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored,
and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal.
```

-9 parameter means you KILL with SIGKILL signal

List of available signals:

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/signals.htm

So the answer is NO, it won't execute since you use kill -9

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use SIGINT to stop your spring boot application gracefully.